# Bootstrap's v4 btn-outline-primary doesn't work

Tags: html, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap's v4 `btn-outline-primary` doesn't work on the nav links when viewed on my iPhone, but works fine (albeit solid without outline) when viewed on my laptop and desktop screens. I looked around and didn't find any solutions specific to this. I'm using Bootstrap 4.0.0.

HTML is:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- START NAVBAR -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- ADDED DIV TO MANIPULATE POSITIONS OF "navbar-brand" and "navbar-nav", the ul -->
      <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">JavaScript Is Cool</span>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <!-- removed .active -->
            <a class="nav-link btn-outline-primary" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link btn-outline-primary" href="/bio">Bio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link btn-outline-primary" href="/history">Resume´</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle btn-outline-primary" href="" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Coming Soon</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Coming Soon</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Coming Soon</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- REMOVED THE SEARCH FORM -->
        <!-- <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form> -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END ADDED DIV -->
  </nav>
  <!-- END NAVBAR -->

  <!-- START JUMBOTRON -->
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col titleDiv">
          <h1 class="line1">RON SMITH</h1>
          <p class="line2">JavaScript Is Cool</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END JUMBOTRON -->

  <!-- START FOOTER -->
  {{>footer}}
  <!-- END FOOTER -->
  <script src="../js/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Everything works fine except when tapping on iPhone. There's no highlighting of the button or links with color in responsive mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `btn-outline-primary` class is **not** designed to be used the way you were using it. So, saying that it *"works fine"* means you misunderstood how it was supposed to work in the first place because based on the current behavior resulting from your code, it does **NOT** work "fine".

To make the `btn-outline-primary` class work the way it's supposed to be used and work, you need to add the `btn` class additionally to that as shown in the code snippet below. In other words, `btn` is **required** for `btn-outline-primary` to work properly even though the effect you get that way might not be the effect you were going for.

Here's the code snippet (click "run code snippet" below and expand to full page):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="container">  <!-- ADDED DIV TO MANIPULATE POSITIONS OF "navbar-brand" and "navbar-nav", the ul -->
        <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">JavaScript Is Cool</span>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">  <!-- removed .active -->
                    <a class="nav-link btn btn-outline-primary" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link btn btn-outline-primary" href="/bio">Bio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link btn btn-outline-primary" href="/history">Resume´</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link btn dropdown-toggle btn-outline-primary" href="" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Coming Soon</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Coming Soon</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Coming Soon</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- REMOVED THE SEARCH FORM -->
            <!-- <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
<input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
<button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form> -->
        </div>
    </div> <!-- END ADDED DIV -->
</nav>
```